# How to serialise into an array of slices?

Tags: rust

Suppose I have a trait representing a pure function; memory has been provided for the outputs, and both inputs and outputs are expected to be serde/bincode encoded.  Is it possible to make this do what I want, or restructure things to enable the same end idiomatically?

```
trait Pure {
    fn pure(inputs: &[&[u8]], outputs: &[&mut [u8]]);
}

struct Identity {}

impl Pure for Identity {
    fn pure(inputs: &[&[u8]], outputs: &[&mut [u8]]) {
        let x: u32 = bincode::deserialize(inputs[0]).expect("input decode failed");
        bincode::serialize_into(outputs[0], &x).unwrap();
    }
}
```

makes the compiler complain:

```
error[E0508]: cannot move out of type `[&mut [u8]]`, a non-copy slice
  --> src/main.rs:10:33
   |
10 |         bincode::serialize_into(outputs[0], &x).unwrap();
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^
   |                                 |
   |                                 cannot move out of here
   |                                 move occurs because `outputs[_]` has type `&mut [u8]`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. First, if you want to be able to mutate the inner references, then you must have a mutable *outer* reference. IOW, your `pure` function should take a `&mut[&mut [u8]]` for parameter.

Second, in order to pass the mutable reference to `deserialize_into`, you need to reborrow it, to make it clear to the compiler that you are not permanently taking it out of `output`:

```
trait Pure {
    fn pure(inputs: &[&[u8]], outputs: &mut[&mut [u8]]);
                                     // ^^^ add this
}

struct Identity {}

impl Pure for Identity {
    fn pure(inputs: &[&[u8]], outputs: &mut[&mut [u8]]) {
                                     // ^^^ add this
        let x: u32 = bincode::deserialize(inputs[0]).expect("input decode failed");
        bincode::serialize_into(&mut*outputs[0], &x).unwrap();
                             // ^^^^^ add this
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=18fddeaa85f2b6644fa0697dffce4689)

Comment: Thank you for the speedy fix!  Adding the outer mut is intuitive in hindsight;  but, woah, "reborrowing" is new to me.  Is there nice documentation somewhere illustrating in more detail the conditions when this is generally needed?

Comment: I'm not sure about documentation on reborrowing. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/788) about improving the documentation (mainly about the implicit/automatic reborrowing that the compiler is able to do in some cases). Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66288291/what-is-a-reborrow-and-how-does-it-influence-the-code-the-compiler-generates) has some explanations about explicit reborrows.