# This example subverts my understanding of ownership and reference scope

Tags: rust, scope, mutable, ownership

```
// print：
//  string-a
//  string-aaabc
fn main() {
    let mut a = String::from("string-");
    
    let s = &mut a;
    
    let ss = &mut a; // s goes out of scope here
    ss.push('a');
    // string-a
    println!("{}", ss.clone()); // ss.clone() ==> borrow shared reference, ss(mutable reference) should be gone out of scope. but it still available. why ???
    ss.push_str("aa"); 
    
    let b = &mut (*ss); // borrow '&mut (*ss)' twice to mutable, ss shoudle be gone out of scope. but it still available. why ???
    // uncommenting，error(cannot borrow `*ss` as mutable more than once at a time)
    //      let b = &mut (*ss); ==> first mutable borrow occurs here  ==> why?
    //      ss.push('d'); ==> second mutable borrow occurs here  ==> why?
    //      b.push('b'); ==> first borrow later used here
    // why ? 
    // ss.push('d');
    
    b.push('b');
    ss.push('c'); // why? ss still available!

    println!("{}", a); // string-aaabc
}
```

This example subverts my understanding of ownership and reference scope. I'm confused.
Questions are like code comments

Comment: This [detailled answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50253558/11527076) about **non-lexical lifetimes** can help.

Answer (score 1):

```
// print：
//  string-a
//  string-aaabc
fn main() {
    let mut a = String::from("string-");
    
    let s = &mut a;
    
    let ss = &mut a; // s goes out of scope here
    ss.push('a');
    // string-a
    println!("{}", ss.clone()); // ss.clone() ==> borrow shared reference, ss(mutable reference) should be gone out of scope. but it still available. why ???
```

`ss.clone` borrows `ss`, it doesn't take ownership. When `clone` returns, it releases the borrow and so `ss` is still available. The fact that `ss` is an exclusive reference (`&mut`) rather than a shared reference (`&`) doesn't change anything here. It only means that no one could have used `ss` until `clone` returned, which is impossible anyway.

```
    ss.push_str("aa"); 
    
    let b = &mut (*ss); // borrow '&mut (*ss)' twice to mutable, ss shoudle be gone out of scope. but it still available. why ???
```

This is called a [reborrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66342968/5397009). At this point:

- `a` is borrowed exclusively by `ss`, so `a` can't be used until `ss` gets dropped.
- `ss` is borrowed exclusively by `b`, so `ss` can't be used until `b` gets dropped. Note that `ss` is only *borrowed* by `b`, not moved, so `ss` will become available again once `b` releases the borrow.

```
    // uncommenting，error(cannot borrow `*ss` as mutable more than once at a time)
    //      let b = &mut (*ss); ==> first mutable borrow occurs here  ==> why?
    //      ss.push('d'); ==> second mutable borrow occurs here  ==> why?
    //      b.push('b'); ==> first borrow later used here
    // why ? 
    // ss.push('d');
```

`b` is still alive and holds an exclusive borrow of `ss`, so `ss` can't be accessed directly.

```
    b.push('b');
```

This is the last time we use `b`, so `b` can be dropped now thanks to [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50253558/11527076), and `ss` becomes available again.

```
    ss.push('c'); // why? ss still available!
```

`b` only borrowed `ss`, it didn't take ownership. So now that `b` has been dropped, the borrow is released and `ss` is available again. For exactly the same reason that `a` is available again on the next line once `ss` has been dropped:

```
    println!("{}", a); // string-aaabc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First, the variants and references are two different things. In general, when you're done using a variant, rust will automatically drop that variable for you.

   ```rust
   let s = &mut a; // s dropped, because it's not used afterwards.
   ```
2. clone: only reference for `ss`
3. `let b = &mut (*ss);` In here, you're not borrowing the `ss` variable instead of getting raw reference `a` that is raw pointer metadata saved by `ss`:

   ```
   b  --> &mut a
   ss --> &mut a
   ```

   - However, problems can be occurred when you use mutable borrowing.

   ```rust
    let b = &mut (*ss); // -------
                        //        |
    b.push('b');        //   ------
    // variant `b` was dropped
    // in here, you can just use `ss`
   ```

If you write it like as follow, which is your confusing, then

```rust
//...
 ss.push('c'); // cannot borrow `*ss` as mutable more than once at a time second mutable borrow occurs hererustcClick for full compiler diagnostic

 b.push('b'); // `b` was not dropped
//...
```